# Where should I ask questions about Structured Framemaker and DITA?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am working on a project to convert our old, unstructured Framemaker documents to be DITA-compliant. Totally stumped on a problem relating to applying display styles to cross-references. Not sure which stackexchange site to post the question on. Help!

Comment: Sounds lke a decent stack question , have at it!

Comment: As it is about a program and not development I wouldtry SuperUser

Answer (score 2):

A little late to the party, but ...

The scope of [Writing Stack Exchange](https://writing.stackexchange.com/) does not only include 'creative' writing, but also [technical writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-writing). They even have [a few questions about DITA](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dita) as well. I'm not sure how actively monitored that part of the site is, so don't have too high hopes of it being answered.

It might be on-topic on Super User as well (as suggested by Mark), but my guess is that Structured Framemaker users aren't likely to be found there; it's too much of a niche product.

<sub>A site dedicated to [Technical Communication](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/101439/technical-communication) alone didn't survive the private beta phase.</sub>

Comment: Writing mod here.  These topics are welcome on Writing.  We even have a DITA tag.

Comment: Always good to have the stamp of approval from a local authority, thanks :)